# Set auto_id in formset and do not disable errors on first display

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am writing the view for following forms:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.fields['question_text'].label = 'Question'


class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice_text',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.fields['choice_text'].label = 'Choice'


ChoiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Question, Choice, form=ChoiceForm,
                                       extra=6, validate_min=1, can_delete=False)

def create_question(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        question_form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        choice_formset = ChoiceFormSet(request.POST)
        if question_form.is_valid() and choice_formset.is_valid():
            question = question_form.save()
            choice_formset.instance = question
            choice_formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:vote', args=(question.id,)))
    else:
        question_form = QuestionForm()
        choice_formset = ChoiceFormSet()

    question_form.auto_id = False
    question_form.use_required_attribute = False

    for form in choice_formset:
        form.auto_id = False
        form.use_required_attribute = False

    return render(request, 'polls/create.html', {'question_form': question_form, 'choice_formset': choice_formset})
```

- The field required error message is also shown the first time the view is displayed
- The form requires the fill out all choices but it should only be one:    `validate_min=1`
- How can `auto_id` and `use_required_attribute` set more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The form was always bound and so the form was invalid. I forgot the asterik in the form super call (`super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`)
- After the solution above the validation also worked
- A formset has also the auto_id property and use_required_attribute disabled by default:

  ```
  question_form.auto_id = False
  choice_form_set.auto_id = False
  question_form.use_required_attribute = False
  ```